# How to build a directed graph with paths shorter than a given size?

Tags: algorithm, graph, language-agnostic

How to build a directed graph with a given number of nodes `N` so that for every pair of nodes there is a path of size < `L`. I'd like also to minimize the number of edges.

Comment: Do the edges all have the same weight?

Comment: Yes (actually it's an unweighted graph).

Comment: This sounds more like a research problem than a programming one.  That said, if `L = 2` then the fully connected graph is the only solution.  If `L` is larger, I would pick one node to be a hub, and then arrange the others into loops around that hub.  If a loop has `K` things in it then in `K` steps you get to the hub and in another `K` steps you get to any other node.  So we want `2K < L`.  I can't guarantee that this is best but it will be pretty good.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense.

Comment: I don't know to which extent you want to be optimal but it seems that generating graph with fixed diameter has been somehow studied for small D (1,2)

Comment: @user753642 Thank you. Now I know what I am looking for :) I am actually trying to build a graph _with fixed diameter_.